# Why does my air conditioner say not to shut it off and restart within 3 minutes?

Tags: air-conditioning

My air conditioner says not to turn it off and then back on within 3 minutes.

Why is that, and what will happen if I do?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like this will answer your question. Found on another Stack Exchange site:
https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/4695/do-air-conditioners-need-a-3-minute-break-after-being-started-or-stopped

Comment: I think the answer to [this question](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/115886/11080) is much better, as it actually explains why. Instead of simply showing that a lot of companies recommend it.